# How to parse rss feed from an android service and update the activity UI from the service?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, android-activity

I am building an RSSReader app to read an RSS Feed and display the data on my MainActivity.

I used a custom ListActivity to display my data. I created a service to download the xml file and parse it. I tried to send back the ArrayList of objects to the MainActivity using Serialization. But an error is coming up saying that "Service couldn't be started".

MainActivity.java

```
package com.saivikas.rssreader;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    String[] titles;
    String[] dates;
    BroadcastReceiver updateUIReceiver;
    public final String ACTION = "com.saivikas.RssReader.MyService";
    public final String KEY = "000";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        this.startService(serviceIntent);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

        filter.addAction(ACTION);

         updateUIReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //UI update here
                ArrayList<Entry> entryList = (ArrayList<Entry>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(KEY);

                Iterator<Entry> it = entryList.iterator();
                int i=0;
                while(it.hasNext()) {
                    Entry currentEntry = it.next();
                    titles[i] = currentEntry.title;
                    dates[i] = currentEntry.pubDate;
                    i++;
                }

                listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);


                int j=0;
                adapter=new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                for (String title:titles) {
                    ListDataProvider dataProvider=new ListDataProvider(titles[i],dates[i]);
                    adapter.add(dataProvider);
                    j++;
                }

            }
         };
        registerReceiver(updateUIReceiver, filter);


//        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
//
//
//            @Override
//            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
//                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), position + "is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), second_class.class);
//                startActivity(myIntent);
//            }
//        });
    }


}
```

MyService.java

```
package com.saivikas.rssreader;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyService extends Service {

    public final String ACTION = "com.saivikas.RssReader.MyService";
    public final String KEY = "000";
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //check for internet connection
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (!netInfo.isConnected())
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not connected to internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            InputStream xmlStream = downloadUrl("http://www.pcworld.com/index.rss");
            XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;

            try {
                pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
                parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                parser.setInput(xmlStream,null);

                parseXML(parser);

            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            is = conn.getInputStream();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return is;
    }

    private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
    {
        ArrayList<Entry> entries = null;
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        Entry currentEntry = null;

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String name = null;
            switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    entries = new ArrayList();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if (name == "item"){
                        currentEntry = new Entry();
                    } else if (currentEntry != null){
                        if (name == "title"){
                            currentEntry.title = parser.nextText();
                        } else if (name == "pubDate"){
                            currentEntry.pubDate = parser.nextText();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("item") && currentEntry != null){
                        entries.add(currentEntry);
                    }
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }

        Intent toSend = new Intent();
        Bundle objBundle = new Bundle();
        objBundle.putSerializable(KEY,entries);
        toSend.putExtras(objBundle);
        toSend.setAction(ACTION);
        this.sendBroadcast(toSend);
    }


}
```

Entry.java

package com.saivikas.rssreader;

```
import java.io.Serializable;


    public class Entry implements Serializable {
        public String title;
        public String pubDate;
    }
```

Error:

```
08-30 16:54:27.628    2917-2917/com.saivikas.rssreader E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.saivikas.rssreader.MyService@420df0b8 with Intent { cmp=com.saivikas.rssreader/.MyService }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is == null
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2859)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1461)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is == null
            at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.setInput(KXmlParser.java:1615)
            at com.saivikas.rssreader.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:45)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2842)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1461)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have seems to be a runtime exception in your `KXmlParser` class that produces a illegalStateException in your Service due the imposibillity of start the services. Look at the call of MyService line 45 that call your KXmlParser class and crash in the line 1615. For the name looks like a InputStream is null or something like that.

My two cents:
Using a `Services` for this is like kill flyes with a tank.
The accepted rule for "non-main-thread" jobs is more or less:
If the requet/work/job could be done in less than 2-3 seconds, dont use services.

A service should be use for thinks like download large files or images, special work that should be done with the app maybe closed ... or stuff like this.

Instead of use a Service try to use a `AsyncTask`[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
It's not perfect and has limitations (probably someone enter to tell you) specially when the user turn the device and Android recreates the layout but it's a perfect for start learn android.
For request and Rest Apis I recommend you to take a look of `Retrofit` library. For this XML parser is a litle more complex because you need a custom parser but try it.

Comment: AsyncTask worked like a charm. Thanks a lot Aracem. My code became more simpler.

Comment: @Vikas please select the answer like correct (clicking in the Tick) and up vote if you can, I think that you can't with your actual points